# Bootstrap - Make Columns Visible/Hidden on Breakpoints Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make my jumbotron mobile responsive. My goal is to have the Logo centered at the top with the search/submit form centered underneath it, contained within the jumbotron, on xs/sm screens only (think iphones, mobile devices). I've tried various methods using multiple rows, or a single row, and using the [Bootstrap Display Properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/) to attempt to hide the second column in my first row on the "sm" breakpoint, while simultaneously making visible the second row/column. I'm sure there is a much better way of doing this (less redundant) but I've been stuck on this for 2 days and not making much progress.

Here is what I've done so far:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('../img/grey_wash_wall.png');
}

.jumbotron {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px black;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
}

#header {
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#header-content {
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

#hubBG {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
  margin: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px yellow;
  border: none;
}

#motto {
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#form {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

#input {
  color: #f8f9fa;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: #f8f9fa73 solid 1px;
  outline: none;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffffff0c;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #f8f9fa73;
}

#btn {
  color: yellow;
  padding: 2px;
}

#btn:hover {
  color: #212529;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Mike's GifHub</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-end">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-sm-center" id="header">
          <h1 id="header-content">Gif<span class="text-dark" id="hubBG">Hub</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 d-sm-none d-md-block" id="form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="bg-dark" id="input">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-light" id="btn">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-end">
        <div class="col-sm-12 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none text-sm-center" id="form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="bg-dark" id="input">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-light" id="btn">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where are your attempts to center the logo and input?

Comment: I edited by adding text-sm-center, which I had before but wasn't working. Thanks for pointing that out though. I forgot that I had deleted it before posting the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "My goal is to have the Logo centered at the top with the search/submit form centered underneath it, contained within the jumbotron, on xs/sm screens only"

Then just use the [responsive text alignment classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#text-alignment) and forget about showing/hiding elements in the duplicate markup.

```
<div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-end">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center text-sm-left" id="header">
          <h1 id="header-content">Gif<span class="text-dark" id="hubBG">Hub</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center text-sm-right" id="form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="bg-dark" id="input">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-light" id="btn">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/hyAO1dxHhG

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for.